# Handler in subdirectory of AWS Lambda function not running

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm getting an awfully unfortunate error on Lambda:

```
Unable to import module 'lib/index': Error
at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
```

Which is strange because there is definitely a function called `handler` getting exported from `lib/index`...not sure if the whole subdirectory thing has been an issue for others so I wanted to ask.

### sam-template.yaml

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: Does something crazy
Resources:
  SomeFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      Handler: lib/index.handler
      Role: arn:aws:iam::...:role/lambda-role
      Runtime: nodejs6.10
      Timeout: 10
      Events:
        Timer:
          Type: Schedule
          Properties:
            Schedule: rate(1 minute)
```

### Module structure

```
|-- lib
|     `-- index.js
`-- src
      `-- index.js
```

I have nested it here because I'm transpiling ES6 during my build process using the following, excerpt from `package.json`:
`"build": "babel src -d lib"`

### buildspec.yaml

```
version: 0.1
phases:
    install:
        commands:
            - npm install
            - aws cloudformation package --template-file sam-template.yaml --s3-bucket some-bucket --output-template-file compiled-sam-template.yaml
    build:
        commands:
            - npm run build
    post_build:
        commands:
            - npm prune --production
artifacts:
    files:
        - 'node_modules/**/*'
        - 'lib/**/*'
        - 'compiled-template.yaml'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `aws cloudformation package` command is shipping the built assets, which is run in the `install` phase of the shown code. Moving it to the `post_build` will ensure it captures everything needed, including the `lib/index` in question:

```
post_build:
  commands:
    - npm prune --production
    - aws cloudformation package ...
```

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to import `lib/index` which will try to find a package named `lib` as if you did `npm install --save lib` but you are most likely trying to import a file relative to your own project and you are not giving it a relative path in your import.

Change `'lib/index'` to `'./lib/index'` - or `'../lib/index'` etc. - depending where it is and see if it helps.

By the way, if you're trying to import the file `lib/index.js` and not a directory `lib/import/` then you may use a shorter `./lib` path, as in:

```
const lib = require('./lib');
```

Of course you didn't show even a single line of your code so I can only guess what you're doing.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Unfortunately I've tried both of the following `Handler` values to no avail:
`Handler: lib/index.handler`
`Handler: './lib/index.handler`

Answer (score 1):

The reference to the handler must be relative to the lambda to be execute;

Ex:
if the file lambda is placed in the path:

```
x-lambda/yyy/lambda.py
```

the handler must be:

```
..yyy/lambda.lambda_handler
```

it suppose that in the lambda.py exist the function: lambda_handler()

Comment: Why do I need a `..` before `yyy`?

Comment: because you need do relative reference to the script

Answer (score 1):

Your handler should be `.lib/index.handler` considering your `index.js` file is in a subdirectory `lib`.

Comment: hello from some years later. saved my day 